# regex letter grouping?

Tags: php, regex

Extract text from URL ?

trying this preg_match

```
/\<a href=([^"]*) .?\>([^\<\/a]*)\<\/a\>+/
```

Not working on

```
<a href="_first.asp?FileName=37479676820111216064143">        
<font size="2" face="Tahoma">
TEXT I WANT TO EXTRACT
</font>
</a>
```

am sure there's something wrong with `([^\<\/a]*)` am just too bad in regex and can't find a good tutorial even !

Comment: Added `php` tag because there are a **lot** of dialects of regular expressions. But as you're using `preg_match`, we can assume PHP's dialect.

Comment: Oh yes sorry i forgot to add it , my brain is busy thinking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the very start, you have `href=`, then any number of non-quotes (which is zero in your example, since the next character is a quote), and then a space (which fails your expression, since the next character is not a quote, but a space).

In any case, while this is doable with regexps as long as the structure doesn't change, [it's not really the way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/240443).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

`/^<a[^>]+>(?:\s*<[^>]+>)*\s*([^<]+)(?:\s*<\/[^>]+>)*\s*<\/a>$/m`

will work?